# How to make an input with javascript jQuery.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Hello Good morning I have this code but you only have 4 colors and I want to make an input to be able to the color # F4F4F4 I want to outside of the canvas but I do not know how to use this example code and the file with everything:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzcdeIOejP5xc29OdnhTRlV4UHc

```
var paintBucketApp = (function () {

"use strict";

var context,
    canvasWidth = 490,
    canvasHeight = 220,
    colorPurple = {
        r: 203,
        g: 53,
        b: 148
    },
    colorGreen = {
        r: 101,
        g: 155,
        b: 65
    },
    colorYellow = {
        r: 255,
        g: 207,
        b: 51
    },
    colorBrown = {
        r: 152,
        g: 105,
        b: 40
    },
    curColor = colorPurple,
    outlineImage = new Image(),
    swatchImage = new Image(),
    backgroundImage = new Image(),
    swatchStartX = 18,
    swatchStartY = 19,
    swatchImageWidth = 93,
    swatchImageHeight = 46,
    drawingAreaX = 111,
    drawingAreaY = 11,
    drawingAreaWidth = 267,
    drawingAreaHeight = 200,
    colorLayerData,
    outlineLayerData,
    totalLoadResources = 3,
    curLoadResNum = 0,

    // Clears the canvas.
    clearCanvas = function () {

        context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
    },

    // Draw a color swatch
    drawColorSwatch = function (color, x, y) {

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x + 46, y + 23, 18, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(" + color.r + "," + color.g + "," + color.b + ")";
        context.fill();

        if (curColor === color) {
            context.drawImage(swatchImage, 0, 0, 59, swatchImageHeight, x, y, 59, swatchImageHeight);
        } else {
            context.drawImage(swatchImage, x, y, swatchImageWidth, swatchImageHeight);
        }
    },

    // Draw the elements on the canvas
    redraw = function () {

        var locX,
            locY;

        // Make sure required resources are loaded before redrawing
        if (curLoadResNum < totalLoadResources) {
            return;
        }

        clearCanvas();

        // Draw the current state of the color layer to the canvas
        context.putImageData(colorLayerData, 0, 0);

        // Draw the background
        context.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

        // Draw the color swatches
        locX = 52;
        locY = 19;
        drawColorSwatch(colorPurple, locX, locY);

        locY += 46;
        drawColorSwatch(colorGreen, locX, locY);

        locY += 46;
        drawColorSwatch(colorYellow, locX, locY);

        locY += 46;
        drawColorSwatch(colorBrown, locX, locY);

        // Draw the outline image on top of everything. We could move this to a separate 
        //   canvas so we did not have to redraw this everyime.
        context.drawImage(outlineImage, drawingAreaX, drawingAreaY, drawingAreaWidth, drawingAreaHeight);
    },

    matchOutlineColor = function (r, g, b, a) {

        return (r + g + b < 100 && a === 255);
    },

    matchStartColor = function (pixelPos, startR, startG, startB) {

        var r = outlineLayerData.data[pixelPos],
            g = outlineLayerData.data[pixelPos + 1],
            b = outlineLayerData.data[pixelPos + 2],
            a = outlineLayerData.data[pixelPos + 3];

        // If current pixel of the outline image is black
        if (matchOutlineColor(r, g, b, a)) {
            return false;
        }

        r = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos];
        g = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 1];
        b = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 2];

        // If the current pixel matches the clicked color
        if (r === startR && g === startG && b === startB) {
            return true;
        }

        // If current pixel matches the new color
        if (r === curColor.r && g === curColor.g && b === curColor.b) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    },

    colorPixel = function (pixelPos, r, g, b, a) {

        colorLayerData.data[pixelPos] = r;
        colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 1] = g;
        colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 2] = b;
        colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 3] = a !== undefined ? a : 255;
    },

    floodFill = function (startX, startY, startR, startG, startB) {

        var newPos,
            x,
            y,
            pixelPos,
            reachLeft,
            reachRight,
            drawingBoundLeft = drawingAreaX,
            drawingBoundTop = drawingAreaY,
            drawingBoundRight = drawingAreaX + drawingAreaWidth - 1,
            drawingBoundBottom = drawingAreaY + drawingAreaHeight - 1,
            pixelStack = [[startX, startY]];

        while (pixelStack.length) {

            newPos = pixelStack.pop();
            x = newPos[0];
            y = newPos[1];

            // Get current pixel position
            pixelPos = (y * canvasWidth + x) * 4;

            // Go up as long as the color matches and are inside the canvas
            while (y >= drawingBoundTop && matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB)) {
                y -= 1;
                pixelPos -= canvasWidth * 4;
            }

            pixelPos += canvasWidth * 4;
            y += 1;
            reachLeft = false;
            reachRight = false;

            // Go down as long as the color matches and in inside the canvas
            while (y <= drawingBoundBottom && matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB)) {
                y += 1;

                colorPixel(pixelPos, curColor.r, curColor.g, curColor.b);

                if (x > drawingBoundLeft) {
                    if (matchStartColor(pixelPos - 4, startR, startG, startB)) {
                        if (!reachLeft) {
                            // Add pixel to stack
                            pixelStack.push([x - 1, y]);
                            reachLeft = true;
                        }
                    } else if (reachLeft) {
                        reachLeft = false;
                    }
                }

                if (x < drawingBoundRight) {
                    if (matchStartColor(pixelPos + 4, startR, startG, startB)) {
                        if (!reachRight) {
                            // Add pixel to stack
                            pixelStack.push([x + 1, y]);
                            reachRight = true;
                        }
                    } else if (reachRight) {
                        reachRight = false;
                    }
                }

                pixelPos += canvasWidth * 4;
            }
        }
    },

    // Start painting with paint bucket tool starting from pixel specified by startX and startY
    paintAt = function (startX, startY) {

        var pixelPos = (startY * canvasWidth + startX) * 4,
            r = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos],
            g = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 1],
            b = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 2],
            a = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 3];

        if (r === curColor.r && g === curColor.g && b === curColor.b) {
            // Return because trying to fill with the same color
            return;
        }

        if (matchOutlineColor(r, g, b, a)) {
            // Return because clicked outline
            return;
        }

        floodFill(startX, startY, r, g, b);

        redraw();
    },

    // Add mouse event listeners to the canvas
    createMouseEvents = function () {

        $('#canvas').mousedown(function (e) {
            // Mouse down location
            var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
                mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

            if (mouseX < drawingAreaX) { // Left of the drawing area
                if (mouseX > swatchStartX) {
                    if (mouseY > swatchStartY && mouseY < swatchStartY + swatchImageHeight) {
                        curColor = colorPurple;
                        redraw();
                    } else if (mouseY > swatchStartY + swatchImageHeight && mouseY < swatchStartY + swatchImageHeight * 2) {
                        curColor = colorGreen;
                        redraw();
                    } else if (mouseY > swatchStartY + swatchImageHeight * 2 && mouseY < swatchStartY + swatchImageHeight * 3) {
                        curColor = colorYellow;
                        redraw();
                    } else if (mouseY > swatchStartY + swatchImageHeight * 3 && mouseY < swatchStartY + swatchImageHeight * 4) {
                        curColor = colorBrown;
                        redraw();
                    }
                }
            } else if ((mouseY > drawingAreaY && mouseY < drawingAreaY + drawingAreaHeight) && (mouseX <= drawingAreaX + drawingAreaWidth)) {
                // Mouse click location on drawing area
                paintAt(mouseX, mouseY);
            }
        });
    },

    // Calls the redraw function after all neccessary resources are loaded.
    resourceLoaded = function () {

        curLoadResNum += 1;
        if (curLoadResNum === totalLoadResources) {
            createMouseEvents();
            redraw();
        }
    },

    // Creates a canvas element, loads images, adds events, and draws the canvas for the first time.
    init = function () {

        // Create the canvas (Neccessary for IE because it doesn't know what a canvas element is)
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
        canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
        document.getElementById('canvasDiv').appendChild(canvas);

        if (typeof G_vmlCanvasManager !== "undefined") {
            canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
        }
        context = canvas.getContext("2d"); // Grab the 2d canvas context
        // Note: The above code is a workaround for IE 8 and lower. Otherwise we could have used:
        //     context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d");

        // Load images
        backgroundImage.onload = resourceLoaded;
        backgroundImage.src = "images/background.png";

        swatchImage.onload = resourceLoaded;
        swatchImage.src = "images/paint-outline.png";

        outlineImage.onload = function () {
            context.drawImage(outlineImage, drawingAreaX, drawingAreaY, drawingAreaWidth, drawingAreaHeight);

            // Test for cross origin security error (SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18)
            try {
                outlineLayerData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
            } catch (ex) {
                window.alert("Application cannot be run locally. Please run on a server.");
                return;
            }
            clearCanvas();
            colorLayerData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
            resourceLoaded();
        };
        outlineImage.src = "images";
    };

return {
    init: init
};
}());
```

this is the code I want to merge:
CSS:

```
#coloreame {width:200px;height:200px;background-color:lightpink;border:2px solid purple;}
```

JS:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",w);
function w(){
  var d = document,
      dv = d.getElementById("coloreame"),
      i = d.getElementById("f");
  i.addEventListener("keypress",c);
function c(e){
var key = "which" in e ? e.which : e.keyCode;
var regex = /[A-Za-z0-9]/;
if(!regex.test(String.fromCharCode(key))) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  return false;
}
dv.style.backgroundColor = "#" + i.value;
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="coloreame"></div>
  <br></br>
  <input type="text" id="f" placehOLDER="Color div">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take some time and edit your question to clearly state what you are trying to do, what results you've had and what specific question we can help you with. We are not going to go out to Google drive and download your source code and inspect it.

Comment: I know but what I want is to make an input to puncture the color that is off the canvas

Comment: To make color as an input you will need to add an input field like a text box onto the HTML on the page, give it an ID then use jQuery to get the value of the element. Then use this value to set the color of your element

Comment: but how can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a new color to your list you need to do the following:

1. Convert the #f4f4f4 to a RGB type value, you can do this online easily or you can do it in code!
2. i. (optional) Create a HTML input field like a text box and use jQuery to extract the value of this field to set the color dynamically
3. Add the color as a variable (eg. `colorLightGrey`)
4. Draw the color swatch

   ```
   locY += 46;
   drawColorSwatch(colorLightGrey, locX, locY);
   ```